# Make JVM/Solr not swap, using mlockall

Tags: linux, unix, solr, jvm, elasticsearch

I saw ElasticSearch provides the mlockall option which permits to keep the JVM heap inside physical memory instead of virtual memory (which may or not be physical), and to avoid swapping the heap.

Is there such an option with Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [mlockall For All article](http://searchhub.org/2013/05/21/mlockall-for-all/) maybe it has some good insight.

Comment: Yes it has! I saw Cassandra, Voldemort and ElasticSearch and was planning to create a Java agent or something similar to handle this. But this just has been done by LucidWorks, like said at the end: https://github.com/LucidWorks/mlockall-agent

Comment: URL not found. Here is link at web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20140428233929/http://searchhub.org/2013/05/21/mlockall-for-all/